# How can I put subindex in variables in python

Tags: python, jupyter, notation

I did this with Julia some time ago:
[image]

Is there a way to put the subindex in python?

I am trying to put `S$_1$` and then I press tab but doesn't seem to work.

I am using the jupyter notebooks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would a subindex even *mean* in Python?

Comment: Python does not support symbolic math variables like Julia does.

Comment: All right! Thank you then @falafelocelot (: